looking for a name for metrics that behave like the longest common prefix

$(M, d)$ is a metric space
$M$ is a semigroup
for all $a, b, c \in M$, $d(a, b) \le d(a, b \| c)$

Is there a name for this? I've (informally) found one solution so far, where $M$ is the set of all strings and $d$ calculates the length of the longest common prefix between two strings.

What means $b|c$?

where $|$ is the semigroup operator (concatenation in the case of strings)

Preliminary remarks.
First, the standard notation for the product of two elements $s$ and $t$ of a semigroup is simply $st$.
Next, the length of the longest common prefix $u \wedge v$ of two words $u$ and $v$ of the free monoid is not a metric. Indeed, $u \wedge u = u$ and this would contradict the condition $d(u, u) = 0$ if $u$ is not the empty word. I suppose you refer to the geodesic metric, defined by
$$
d(u, v) = |u| + |v| - 2 |u \wedge v|
$$
This is indeed a metric, but it does not satisfy your condition since
if $A = \{a,b,c\}$, $d(abc,a) = 2$ but $d(abc,ab) = 1$.
Answer to your question.
Your condition implies that your semigroup $M$ satisfies the identity
$xy = x$ for all $x, y \in M$. Indeed, according to your condition, one has for every $x \in M$,
$$
d(xy,x) \leqslant d(xy, xy) =  0
$$
whence $d(xy,x) = 0$ and $xy = x$. Of course, if $M$ satisfies this identity, then any distance on $M$ satisfies your condition.
Note that if $M$ is a monoid with identity $1$ satisfies your condition, then it is the trivial monoid. Indeed
$$
d(x,1) \leqslant d(x, 1x) = d(x,x) = 0
$$
whence $x = 1$.
